# how to select a particular set of data from database and put on excel.csv format and be downloadable. thanks

Tags: jquery, ajax, navicat

A user would be asked the course code and on selecting it should automatically download all the matriculation number registered to the course code and put it on the excel file format to be downloaded by the user.  thanks cause i have tried all i could.

Comment: *"thanks cause i have tried all i could"* please, show us and point out where it went wrong.

Comment: While we're at it, hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is your plan to implement these things. Please mention that too.